# JPA joinColumn error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am trying to simulate a one-one relationship. When i try to add the nullable = false ,
in the join column attribute, i get an SQLIntegrityContraintViolationException saying that the ID of address is null. I am expecting this because, the auto-generated value that i am using in the id is generated at the commit time. (Am i RIGHT ?) ...

But, when i make a modification in the address constructor, by setting an id there and then trying to persist.. i am getting the same exception. I do not understand why.

However, if i remove the nullable = false, i can exeucte it normally. Please explain where i am going wrong.

Here are my implementations.. Getters and Setters were omitted for simplicity.

```
  @Entity
    public class CustomerEX implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
        @JoinColumn(name="address_fk")  
        private AddressEx address;

  public void setAddress(AddressEx address) {
    this.address = address;
    this.address.setCustomer(this);
 }

        ---
        ----
    }

and 

       @Entity
    public class AddressEx implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        private String city;
        private String country;
        @OneToOne
        private CustomerEX customer;
        }
```

and my main function is like ...

```
public class CustomerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AddressEx addr = new AddressEx();
        addr.setCity("Bangalore");
        addr.setCountry("India");
        System.out.println(addr.getId()+ " is the id of this object");
        CustomerEX cust = new CustomerEX();
        cust.setName("ravi");

        cust.setAddress(addr);

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenceAppPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        EntityTransaction etx = em.getTransaction();                 
        etx.begin();
        em.persist(cust);
        etx.commit();
    }
}
```

Where am i going wrong ?

Comment: Try adding em.flush() after em.persist().

Answer (score 0):

You should cascade the persist action from customer to address.
You're saving the customer but the address doesn't have an Id yet because it is generated